# why are my buttons not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create an array of buttons as a simulation of a seatingChart, but the buttons wont show up on the screen only the frame shows up. what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class guiCreator extends JFrame
{
    public guiCreator()
    {
        setTitle("Seats");
        setSize(500, 600);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
             {  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {  System.exit(0);
                }
             } );

          Container contentPane = getContentPane();
          contentPane.add(new seatingPanel());
        setVisible(true);  
    }

}

class seatingPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public seatingPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel4seating = new JPanel();//creating a grid panel
        panel4seating.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 10));//setting the layout of the grid panel

        JButton [] seats = new JButton [40]; //creating a pointer to the buttonsArray
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            seats[i] = new JButton();//creating the buttons
            seats[i].addActionListener(this);
            panel4seating.add(seats[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {


    }
    //main
    guiCreator flightSeats = new guiCreator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `JPanel` in `seatingPanel`'s constructor, but you're not adding it to the `seatingPanel` itself, so it won't show up at all.

Try adding it to the seatingPanel's layout.

(Or do away with that sub-panel entirely - set the grid layout and and the buttons directly to your `seatingPanel`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiCreator extends JFrame
{
    public GuiCreator()
    {
        super("Seats");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new SeatingPanel());

        pack();    

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiCreator();
    }
}

class SeatingPanel extends JPanel
{
    public SeatingPanel()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel4seating = new JPanel();//creating a grid panel
        panel4seating.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 10));//setting the layout of the grid panel

        JButton [] seats = new JButton [40]; //creating a pointer to the buttonsArray
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            seats[i] = new JButton();//creating the buttons
            //better to set the preferred size of the button
            seats[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,25));
            panel4seating.add(seats[i]);
        }

        add(panel4seating, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

- GUIs should be created on the EDT (my laziness).
- Use camel case for names.
- It is not necessary to extend either `JFrame` or `JPanel` in this instance.

The other (undocumented) changes to the source are improvements.  If you have questions on any part of the changes, ask.

Comment: thank you very much it works? can you check if I am doing the action listener correct? im trying to create a seating chart and whenever that button is clicked an action is performed. I want to refer to the button using its index. and if I add another JPanel with a different set of buttons will I use the same actionListener